# Как объединить несколько CSV файлов в один?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, обработка-данных

Есть несколько CSV файлов, которые я хочу объединить в один.

Изначально воспользовался [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17749365/564240), который предлагает следующее:

```py
import fileinput
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*.csv")

with open('result.csv', 'w') as file:
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
```

Проблема оказалась в том, что при объединении не добавляется перенос строки после очередного файла (т.е. первая строка второго файла оказывается совмещена с последней строкой первого файла). Кроме того, каждый CSV файл имеет заголовок (одинаковый для всех), который хорошо бы убрать у всех фалов, кроме первого.

Сейчас объединяю вручную:

```py
with open(target_filename, 'w') as target_file:
    file_counter = 0
    for file_ in files:
        line_counter = 0
        for line in open(file_, 'r'):
            if line_counter == 0 and file_counter > 0:
                target_file.write('\r\n')    
            else:
                target_file.write(line)
            line_counter += 1
        file_counter += 1
```

Каким образом сделать объединение эффективнее?

Comment: Влезет ли объединенный (склеенный) CSV файл в RAM компьютера, на котором вы обрабатываете данные?

Comment: @MaxU Да, влезет! С другой стороны, было бы очень интересно посмотреть на решение с ограничением на память.

Comment: А ОС какая ? а то мне "эффективнее" и "питон" кажутся не очень совместимыми понятиями :) Хотя я могу быть конечно предвзят. но sed добавить переводы кареток к файлам где их нет и объеденить потом cat будет думаю быстрее на nix системах

Comment: @Mike MacOS. Про утилиты командной строки думал, но показалось питоном быстрее разобраться =)

Comment: тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082204/add-a-newline-only-if-it-doesnt-exist обещают что под osX `sed -i '' -n p *.txt` добавит переводы кареток если их нет. А сборка файлов в один на любых nix* подобных системах будет `cat *.txt >newfilename` :)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Подскажите, что делать с заголовками? Надо пропустить первую строку всех файлов, кроме первого.

Comment: Ну вот тут уже слишком много условий начинается. надо отдельно сохранить 1ю строку что бы потом одинаково обрабатывать все. потом вооружаться find для перебора файлов и выполнения для этого списка `sed '1d'` (не удалять же ее в каждом файле отдельно, сохраняя его при этом), потом еще совместить с тем что строку последнюю правит ... в общем придумывать и отлаживать дольше чем готовый питон файл обработает и тут уже выигрыш по скорости мизерный, sed все равно придется построчно файл пробегать, а не блочно ... Оптимизация хорошо, но свое время то же надо оптимизировать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант предусматривающий жесткие ограничения по памяти - читаем каждый CSV по частям (параметр: `chunksize` - число строк в каждой части) и дописываем по частям в результирующий файл:

```
import pandas as pd    #  pip install pandas
from pathlib import Path

def csv_merger(path, out_filename="res.csv", globmask="*.csv", chunksize=5000, **kwargs):
    path = Path(path)
    need_header = True
    for f in path.glob(globmask):
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=chunksize, **kwargs):
            chunk.to_csv(out_filename, index=False, header=need_header, mode="a")
            need_header = False
```

Пример использования:

```
csv_merger("/data", "/tmp/res.csv", globmask="*.csv", chunksize=1000)
```

**Отказ от ответственности**: данный код не тестировался, поэтому возможны ошибки.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd    #  pip install pandas
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path("/path/to/csv/files/")

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in data_dir.glob("*.csv")], ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("/path/to/result.csv", index=False)
```

---

PS данное решение подразумевает, что объединенный (склеенный) CSV файл умещается в RAM компьютера.

Answer (score 4):

[Вариант решения с использованием UNIX утилиты `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558965):

```
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *.csv > /path/to/res.csv
```

PS данный вариант должен работать гораздо быстрее, т.к. не парсит данные и awk написан на C/C++

Comment: Сомневыюсь, что написан на плюсах (может какой дериват), скорее чистый си.